# How to search for an inspect element without using the F12 menu

Tags: python, selenium, web-inspector

Is there a way to find an inspect element without opening the f12 menu?

Comment: In firefox, just click right mouse button over the interesting element and click "Inspect element"

Answer (score -1):

In chrome and a few other browsers you can hit "Ctrl+Shift+I"